# Windows: How to redirect udp traffic to another port

Tags: networking, window, virtual-machine, port, virtualbox

I currently have a virtual machine running on Windows. The VM is running Linux and has a virtual box network between the windows machine and the linux machine. The VM is running a application that I want to be able to connect to from the outside world.

To make this possible I tried port forwarding from the windows internet interface, to the windows virtualbox interface. Finally I created another port forward from the windows virtualbox interface to the Virtual machine interface.

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=5000 listenaddress=10.11.65.103 connectport=7890 connectaddress=192.168.56.1

netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=7890  listenaddress=192.168.56.1 connectport=5000 connectaddress=192.168.56.101
```

So if I connect to the 10.11.65.103:5000 on the Windows Machine it will be the same thing as connecting to 192.168.56.101:5000 of the VM.

```
[Win Internet Intf]     [Win VM Intf]              [VM intf]
10.11.65.103:5000<----->192.168.56.1:7890 <------> 192.168.56.101:5000
```

Unfortunately, this is not working for me... Can someone tell me why? Am I using port forwarding correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a bridged network adapter your Linux machine should pick up an IP off the host network (if you have DHCP enabled on the network, or set a static IP on the linux box). Then you should then not need the port forwarding.
If you cant use that approach and are using a NAT adapter (which it looks like you are), then you will need to enable port forwarding within VB. The details are in section 6.3 of the [VB Help](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_bridged) with this in place you should only then need the first port forward, VB will be doing the second.

Dont forget to make sure the relevant firwalls on the Windows and Linux machines are open.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, and let you know if it works. I presume I'll still need to do a port foward for the windows side so the information can be forwarded between interfaces?

Comment: For NAT method, yes.